# Git: why necessary to update master first?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, git-rebase

I forked an open source project (let's call it project X). In my own fork, I created a new branch (let's call it `feature-branch-1`) to work on a feature for the next version of X. The owners of X created a new branch for the next version (let's call it `X/nextgen`). Once I was done with my work in `feature-branch-1`, I would submit a pull request with `X/nextgen` as the base.

Of course, between the time that I forked X, and the time that I was ready to submit a pull request, there were some changes in X. `X/netxgen` was up-to-date with `X/master`, so I decided to simply rebase `feature-branch-1` using `X/nextgen`. It worked fine on my end. Git (terminal) showed no merge conflicts, and that `feature-branch-1` was up-to-date with `X/nextgen`. However, when I tried to submit a pull request, Github said that it couldn't merge automatically.

I researched online to find what I was doing wrong. Although I couldn't find any information on direct causes, I came across a lot of guides on how to rebase. Most of these guides stated that *first* the `master` of my own fork should be brought up-to-date with `X/master`, and then `feature-branch-1` should be rebased using the `master` of my own fork. I followed this, and although `feature-branch-1` didn't change any more (I had already rebased using `X/nextgen` -- which was up-to-date with `X/master`), Github was now able to merge my pull request automatically.

So my question is, why could not have I got my pull request to work by just rebasing `feature-branch-1` using `X/nextgen` (without touching `master` of my own fork)? Why does `master` of my own fork need to updated first?

Comment: If `nextgen` updated all you needed to do was pull `nextgen` and rebase against that. `master` has nothing to do with `nextgen`.

Comment: That's what I thought! But it didn't work out that way.. I followed [this guide](http://blog.michelemattioni.me/2013/01/29/what-do-i-do-when-my-pull-request-does-not-merge-automatically-in-master/) where it mentions to update your own `master` and then rebase off of that. It worked after that. So I was just wondering if there is some concept that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to only rebase `feature-branch-1` commits on top of the target branch, which is `upstream/X/nextgen`, with `upstream` being the name of the original repository remote URL.

No need to update any of your local branch (like `master`, `X` or `X/nextgen`)
Since you do not modify your local branches, you can isolate your own commits, and move only those commits:

```bash
git fetch upstream
git rebase --onto upstream/X/nextgen master feature-branch-1
```

That way, your PR will include only the commits you did on `feature-branch-1`, and those commits are on top of the target branch.